# PHP error_reporting calculator

Tags: php, web-applications

I'm looking for a tool to help me with analyzing and setting `error_reporting` levels in PHP.

I'd like it to have the following features:

- Paste a numeric `error_reporting()` value and see all the single error reporting bits that are set in it
- A list of all possible error levels with checkboxes. Checking them generates the PHP code to set it.
- (optional) Select the PHP versions the generated PHP code must run under and generate the code that works for all of them. Important when setting e.g. `E_DEPRECATED` that exists from 5.3 on, but not in 5.2
- (optional) Web application I can run in my browser

---

Does such a tool exist? Where?

Comment: What does this mean: "Select the PHP versions the code must run under and generate the code that works for all of them"? About which code are you speaking, the different error levels?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As to the date there still seems to be no tool which does calculating both ways (between individual constants and bitmask value).

So I wrote one: https://maximivanov.github.io/php-error-reporting-calculator/

It's a web app that will help you:

- calculate error reporting level by picking individual error constants
- see which constants are set by entering error reporting level bitmask number

Comment: Big +1 for the online calculator, very useful and a timer saver, thank you. 

Answer (score 19):

This tool has some of the features you want:

http://www.bx.com.au/tools/ultimate-php-error-reporting-wizard

Comment: .. except for pasting a numeric `error_reporting()` value, but that's ok.

Comment: Actually has that functionality now.

Comment: max_i's calculator in his answer is much improved and allows you to paste in a code to do a reverse lookup on the computed value. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/37091275/292408

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of all defined error constants [in the manual](http://php.net/errorfunc.constants). Note, that this are not flags, but it is a bitmask, so you can't get a list of "flags". To find out, wether a specific error level is covered by a bitmask, or not, or to combine several error levels, use common bit operation

```
var_dump(error_reporting() & E_ERROR); // Test, if ERROR is set
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_NOTICE); // Set both ERROR and NOTICE
```

Comment: yes, I can manually check each single bit if it's set, but that does not help me in any way to get a quick overview what bits are set.

Comment: Just iterate over all levels? I've linked the manual page with a list of all existing.

Comment: @cweiske honestly, dude, if you need this useless calculator, it is a matter of half a hour programming. you'd wasted already more than that.

Comment: The concept is useful if he's looking to spread the tool/provide it to others, say...

Answer (score -6):

the tool you are looking for is

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

All other tools will be either useless or harmful

Comment: I think you are saying errors should never be turned off, but the way you say it without any explanation and in a condescending manner is useless and harmful.